# Why is resetting a timer delayed in my app? Initial start is 20 seconds, but every reset of the timer starts from 0 then 19

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a quiz app and my problem is whenever the time runs out the new timer starts from 0 after re-render and moves to 19 instead of 20.

I've made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8pfcdu?file=src/App.js) with minimum required code to showcase my problem.

It works properly in my app if i click an answer and it starts from 20 seconds. Only happens when i let the timer run out. The methods to reset the timer are same in both ways when someone clicks an answer in the full app, it only has some extra stuff for example getting new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just changed the first useEffect.
I see two thing are wrong here. The `setInterval` has 19 as timeout. It should be 20, because it's the exact milliseconds you need to run that interval.

And second thing is, you're checking whether the `timerWidth > 100` it will be ticked only if the value is above the 100. But in your case, you have to reset the timer just when the timerWidth is 100. So changing `timerWidth >= 100` will work.

Here is the useEffect with changes

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (answer === null && timerWidth < 100.1) {
      timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setTimerWidth(timerWidth + 0.1);
        if (timerWidth >= 100) {
          setTimerWidth(0);
          setSecondsRemaining(20);
        }
      }, 20);
    }
```

Forgive if the explanation is not that good. I'm not a native english speaker. If anyone can explain better, please go ahead.

Comment: Well, first of all thanks for your answer, changing the timerWidth >= 100 fixed the issue with the countdown reset delay. However with the setinterval frequency i initially used 20 ms, but i noticed that it actually takes 21 seconds with a few ms difference every time to fill the bar to 100 even though the math says i'd need 20 ms to fill a 100% width bar with 0,1% increments. So i was messing around and increased the frequency by 5% which is 19 instead of 20 and it actually made the timer go 5% faster too and it's very close to 20 seconds with the 19ms intervals. Hence the 19 ms setinterval.